# iOS - top cells moved up away from the screen when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uikeyboard

Here is before the keyboard shows:

[image: before the keyboard shows]

Here is after the keyboard shows:

[image: when the keyboard shows]

Here is what I want:
If there are enough messages, when move all of them up. If not, like shown in these two images above, then do not move the messages up.
What should I do?

By the way, I use Swift.

Thank you so much!

Comment: how much have you tried?

Comment: use `contentInset`

Comment: I used the IQKeyboardManager and that's all I had done.

Comment: Can you provide us your code/storyboard so we can see how you declare your interface?
I think that you need to remove the constraint to the bottom but I don't know what is your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Because i can't add a comment. so i had to help you in this way.

1. You can provide us more information about table view's constraint. because if you listening keyboard notification and change constraint, maybe will become like this
2. If you use frame property to build this, the same point with first
3. You can run project and use xcode's Debug view hierarchy tool, to check tableview's state. check it's because table view's frame change and be clipped or you change table view's contentInset or other properties to made it ,like this
   [image]